# A JavaScript client for consuming Axis2 service

Tags: javascript, web-services, client, apache-axis

I have written a service using Axis2. Now I wish to consume it using a browser based client written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options when deploying an Axis2 service, ranging from the webservice style (ex: RPC), encoding, transport (tcp/http), handlers, attachments, WS-Security, etc. which makes it hard or impossible to implement a fully compliant Axis2 client.

I would strongly recommend you publish your services enabling the REST api and consume the services via REST. Here's the link to the docs: http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_5/rest-ws.html

If you want to take the hard route and parse soap messages, I would recommend that you write your client using [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) and expose some services using [GWT exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/)